# How to encode url path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urlencode

I have to make network requests to an API endpoint. However requests only encodes query parameters and not the url path.
Consider below for exmaple
`https://example.com/Nova#123`

The server endpoint however accepts `https://example.com/Nova%23123`. How can I do this with requests? String replacement is not a solution considering other special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [urllib.parse.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote):

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin, quote
print(urljoin('https://example.com', quote('Nova#123')))
```

Out:

```
https://example.com/Nova%23123
```

Comment: Thank you. That's really what I was looking for.